# How can I count the number of newline characters at the end of a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

For example I have a string that looks like the following:

```
var example_string = "this is the example string\n <-don't want \n\n\n";
```

Here I've made a string that has four newline characters in it, with three consecutive on the end.  How can I programmatically have javascript tell me that there are 3 newline characters on the end?

Comment: Just in case...
example_string.trim()
does the job; no \n count however..

Comment: (`trim()` is an ECMAScript Fifth Edition feature, originally from Mozilla; it's not supported in all browsers yet, so if you want to use it you have to sniff for it and add a fallback implementation to `String.prototype`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
example_string.match(/\n*$/)[0].length
```

(`\n*$` = 0 or more newlines before the end of the string, `.match(...)[0]` = the whole string which was matched)